# Is this configuration OK for an air admittance valve?

Tags: air

Is this configuration OK for an air admittance valve with the valve on the opposite (right) side of the drain pipe?

The sink drains just as fast with or without the air admittance valve though it seems a bit slow either way.

[image: Drain Setup]

[image: Air Admittance Valve up behind sink]

[image: Completed project per helpful comments]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placement of the AAV is ok, but the drain set up is bad.
There appears to be a tilt to the right of the tub, which will make water sit there.

The "T" needs to be turned 90 deg. and attached to the vertical drain. (Blue)

A horizontal connection (yellow) is connecting the "P" trap and the verticle drain.

The line to the AAV (red) is then run up and high to the back of the tub with a little tilt to the vertical drain. ( no low spots to collect water.)

[image]

Comment: I wonder if user171896's camera was crooked.

Comment: maybe...but it's all wrong anyway.

Comment: The "T" is actually just a barely a bit higher than the pipe on either side. What I understand from RMDman is to put the "T" like this:  |-   The AAV would connect at the top and the p-trap in the middle. Correct?

Comment: @user17189r, That is correct.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get a new picture in this comment. CTRL-G doesn't work, as I don't know the link/url for creating an insert for a local picture. So, you just get a description......... The new improved version thanks to the two tips is all under the sink. The weir outlet tube is very slightly tipped down toward the drain. Everything is now on the left side with the AAV above the "T." The old cheap valve still works just as good as the new Oatey one I tried so I'll probably take the Oatey one back. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks! The drain is very slightly tipped to the left but not as much as it looks in this summary photo.

Comment: It all looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a lot of pipe business for no purpose there. You could use a longer tailpiece at the sink drain opening (12" tailpieces are readily available) and have a standard P-trap going to a sanitary tee on top of the vertical drain, with the AAV on top of that. That way, all the drain piping is tucked underneath the sink. AAV specs typically only require them to be 4" above the trap weir. Please get rid of all that baling wire.

Drains always work better with a real vent-to-atmosphere rather than an AAV.